# Durandal - custom modal click event binding error

Tags: knockout.js, modal-dialog, durandal

I'm having troubles with customs modals and mapping the click events from the modal viewmodel. The code is structured as following, first I'm mapping a headerView in a shell.js like this...

```
<div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/header', preserveContext: true "></div>
```

then in the header.js I'm requiring a separate module, notification....

### Header.js

```
define(function (require) {
'use strict'

var ko = require('knockout'),
router = require('plugins/router'),
notification = require('models/notification');

var HeaderViewModel = function () {

var self = this;

self.title = ko.observable('');

self.toggleMenu = function () {
document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('selected');
};

self.setPage = function (target) {
document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('selected');
self.title(target);
//router.navigate('#' + target);
};

self.activate = function () {
notification.showMatch();
};

};

return new HeaderViewModel();
});
```

I'm targeting the showMatch function in the activate function just to fire and test the modal.

### notification.js

```
define(function (require) {

var Notification = function () {

var self = this;

var matcher = require('models/matcher'),
app = require('durandal/app'),
dialog = require('plugins/dialog'),
modalMatch = require('viewmodels/modalMatch');

self.showMatch = function () {

modalMatch.show().then(function(data) {
//callback function here (called after dialog is closed)
//also will return any passed data
alert('close test');
});

},


self.activate = function() {
this.showMatch();
}

};

return new Notification();
});
```

### modalMatch.js

```
define(['plugins/dialog', 'plugins/router', 'knockout'], function (dialog, router, ko) {
"use strict";

var modalMatch = function (title) {
};

modalMatch.prototype.ok = function () {
dialog.close(this);
};

modalMatch.prototype.go = function (target) {
dialog.close(this);
alert(target);
//router.navigate('#' + target);
};

modalMatch.prototype.show = function () {
return dialog.show(this);
};

return new modalMatch();
});
```

### modalMatch.html

```
<div class="modal ">
<div class="box">
<h3 class="title">Title</h3>

<div class="section">
<a href="#" class="selected">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="section">
<a  data-bind="click: $parent.go('home')" class="button chat">Home</a>
<a  data-bind="click: $parent.go('chat')" class="button sign">Chat</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This will fire up the modal and it will be displayed properly, but the data-bind clicks will not respond the the go function call that is supposed to alert the target argument, close the dialog and navigate to the target.

The console will log the following error 
    Unable to process binding click: function (){return go('chat') }
    Message: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined;
    View: views/modalMatch;
    ModuleId: viewmodels/modalMatch

I guess I have missed some detail in the setup, any help appreciated.

Comment: The title of your post is inappropriate.  Should we take you seriously? The title would suggest we should not.

Comment: I have updated the post with proper title and code example in the description.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 <a  data-bind="click: $parent.go('home')" class="button chat">Home</a>
```

use:

```
 data-bind="click: function(){ $root.go('home'); }
```

or better:

```
 data-bind="click: function(){ $root.go($data); }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I changed the code in the modal view html according to the suggestion. The console will not alert any errors during init load now, but nothing happens when clicking the a-link. It's not firing the go function. It's not responding to the click.